# Enumerating Available Camera Resolutions via DirectShow

Tags: wpf, directshow

I am trying to enumerate a USB camera’s video resolutions using DirectShow accessed from WPF through COM.
I have the following test code.

```
var videoOutPin = this.BaseFilterObject.GetPin(PinDirection.Output, 0);

var streamConfig = (IAMStreamConfig)videoOutPin;

var piCount = 0;
var piSize = 0;

if (streamConfig.GetNumberOfCapabilities(ref piCount, ref piSize) != 0)
{
    return;
}

this.mediaTypes = new Collection<AMMediaType>();

var resolutions = new Collection<string>();

var ptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(piSize);

for (var i = 0; i < piCount; i++)
{
    var mediaType = new AMMediaType();
    if (streamConfig.GetStreamCaps(i, ref mediaType, ptr) != 0)
    {
        continue;
    }

    var header = (VideoInfoHeader)Marshal.PtrToStructure(mediaType.FormatPtr, typeof(VideoInfoHeader));

    var resolution = header.BmiHeader.BitCount + " bits : " + header.BmiHeader.Width + " * " + header.BmiHeader.Height;

    this.mediaTypes.Add(mediaType);
    resolutions.Add(resolution);
}
```

However, I believe that mediaType is picking up some audio capabilities as well as video. E.g. every other iteration gives me a header.BmiHeader.Width of 0 and a header.BmiHeader.BitCount of 0.

Firstly, am I right in thinking this is resulting from casting audio capabilities using  VideoInfoHeader.

How would I enumerate only the video capabilities and eliminate audio?

==============================

## EDIT

I used the DirectShow Capture Capabilities tool and got the following for the suspect capability:

Capability: 1

- `AM_MEDIA_TYPE`:

  - Data: `76 69 64 73 00 00 10 00 80 00 00 AA 00 38 9B 71 59 55 59 32 00 00 10 00 80 00 00 AA 00 38 9B 71 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 60 09 00 A0 76 2A F7 0A EB D0 11 AC E4 00 00 C0 CC 16 BA 00 00 00 00 70 00 00 00 40 07 B3 03`
  - Format Data: `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CA 08 00 00 00 00 15 16 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 81 26 8D 00 00 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 80 02 00 00 E0 01 00 00 01 00 10 00 59 55 59 32 00 60 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`
  - `.subtype`: `FourCC YUY2`
  - `.bFixedSizeSamples`: `1`
  - `.bTemporalCompression`: `0`
  - `.lSampleSize`: `614,400`
  - `.cbFormat`: `112`
  - `VIDEOINFOHEADER2`:
- Unknown Capabilities:

  - Type: `{F72A76A0-EB0A-11D0-ACE4-0000C0CC16BA}`
  - Data: `A0 76 2A F7 0A EB D0 11 AC E4 00 00 C0 CC 16 BA 00 00 00 00 80 02 00 00 E0 01 00 00 80 02 00 00 E0 01 00 00 80 02 00 00 E0 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 80 02 00 00 E0 01 00 00 80 02 00 00 E0 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 15 16 05 00 00 00 00 00 15 16 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CA 08 00 00 CA 08`

Does this make any sense???

==============================

## EDIT #2

Following Roman R.'s advice (if I understand it correctly).

I declare:-

```
private static readonly Guid VideoInfo =
        new Guid(0x05589F80, 0xC356, 0x11CE, 0xBF, 0x01, 0x00, 0xAA, 0x00, 0x55, 0x59, 0x5A);
```

Then modify the code as follows:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < piCount; i++)
        {
            var mediaType = new AMMediaType();
            if (streamConfig.GetStreamCaps(i, ref mediaType, ptr) != 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

           if (mediaType.FormatType != VideoInfo)
            {
                continue;
            }

            Marshal.PtrToStructure(mediaType.FormatPtr, typeof(VideoInfoHeader));

            var header = (VideoInfoHeader)Marshal.PtrToStructure(mediaType.FormatPtr, typeof(VideoInfoHeader));

            var resolution = header.BmiHeader.BitCount + " bits : " + header.BmiHeader.Width + " * "
                             + header.BmiHeader.Height;

            this.mediaTypes.Add(mediaType);
            resolutions.Add(resolution);
        }
```

The above change seems to work e.g. it is working on my test camera. Does this look correct. Is there anything else I should be worried about with this code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe that mediaType is picking up some audio capabilities as well as video. [...]
>
> How would I enumerate only the video capabilities and eliminate audio?

Even though possible, it is highly unlikely that video and audio capabilities and media types are mixed on a specific pin. That is, enumerate it right and you get just video ones, or just audio ones depending on the pin.

You can always compare your enumeration with media types shown by GraphEdit, [GraphStudioNext](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next) or [DirectShowCaptureCapabilities](http://alax.info/blog/1531).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have updated my question with some data. I am not sure why there is unknown capabilities....???

Comment: OK, so you have a half of them of `FORMAT_VideoInfo` and the other half is `FORMAT_VideoInfo2`. You need to check `Type` field to tell one from another.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified the code and updated my question. It seems to work with my test cameras. Am I right in thinking that I will only have to deal with two formats FORMAT_VideoInfo and FORMAT_VideoInfo2?

Comment: Yes, skipping format you don't want to handle is okay.